# manage fields is missing

Tags: entities, nodes

I created new content, but I can't see manage field. I googled the problem, all the solutions say enable Field UI module, I did enable the Field UI, but still I can't see the manage fields, any help please?

Comment: Where are you looking?

Answer (score 1):

Did you flush all caches under `Performance settings`? You can do it manually too. Go to `phpmyadmin` and clear all tables with "cache" preposition. If you use `admin_menu` module, it need to be rebuild from time to time.

Try to access manage_fields manually on path `https://www.yourdomain.com/admin/structure/types/manage/page/fields`

- `page` is name of your content type

When I'm facing strange problem I always try to reproduce it on new Drupal installation. It tells me a lot when I'm "reverse-engineering" the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to flush your caches.  You can do this in any one of the following ways:

- Navigate to /admin/config/development/performance and click "Clear all caches"
- If you have devel installed, hover over the house icon in the toolbar and then click on "Flush all caches"
- If you have command line access and drush installed, run "drush cc all"

Failing that, are you looking in the correct part of the menu, it should be under `structure` -> `Content types` -> `[your content type]` -> `Manage fields`